# Why do I get method does not exist or incorrect signature error using comparable interface?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am attempting to sort a list based on user clicking columns on visualforce page.  Seems like the comparable interface is the best way to do this.

I can sort using static variables but it's messy.  I would like to have dynamic variable to compare the list elements; however, I am receiving an error  -- "Method does not exist or incorrect signature."  Any help is greatly appreciated.

This works but I will need many more if else conditions, one for each column. Plus a check to see what column the user clicked.

```
if(Load.origincity > Loadtocomp.load.origincity)  
          return SortOrder.equals('asc') ? 1 : 0;  
        else  
          return sortOrder.equals('asc') ? 0 : 1;
```

This way is much cleaner but it's not working.

```
if((string)Load.get(comparefield) > (string)Loadtocomp.load.get(comparefield))  
          return SortOrder.equals('asc') ? 1 : 0;  
        else  
          return sortOrder.equals('asc') ? 0 : 1;
```

This is full comparable interface class (with error)::::

```
public class loadsort implements Comparable  
    {  
      public parseUtility.load load {get; set;}   

      public loadsort(parseutility.load ld)  
      {  
        load = ld;  
      }  

      public Integer compareTo(Object vLoad)  
      {  
        loadsort LoadToComp = (loadsort )vLoad;  

        if((string)Load.get(comparefield) > (string)Loadtocomp.load.get(comparefield))  
          return SortOrder.equals('asc') ? 1 : 0;  
        else  
          return sortOrder.equals('asc') ? 0 : 1;  
      }  
    }
```

This is the error:::::: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [ParseUtility.load].get(String)

Comment: ParseUtility must be a class, Load an inner class within ParseUtility and get(String s) a method within Load. However, 'get' may run afoul of reserved words in the compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I didn't have an instance method in my parseutiiity class.  I just needed to pass the argument into the method and return a value based on some condition.

```
   public String get(String arg) {
      if (arg == 'age') {
        return age;
      }
      if (arg == 'companyName') {
        return companyName;
      }
}
```